# subset() a factor by its number of observation

Tags: r, frequency, subset

I have a problem with subset()function. How can I subset a factor of my dataframe by its number of observation?

```
   NAME      CLASS         COLOR   VALUE      
   antonio       B          YELLOW       5
   antonio       B          BLUE       8
   antonio       B          BLUE       7 
   antonio       B          BLUE      12 
   luca          C          YELLOW    99
   luca          B          YELLOW    87
   luca          B          YELLOW    98
   giovanni      A          BLUE      48
```

I would like to obtain data where the three factors "NAME","CLASS" and "COLOR" compare at least three times in order to make a mean of VALUE. in this case I'll obtain:

```
   NAME      CLASS         COLOR   VALUE      
   antonio       B          BLUE       mean
```

because antonio is the only with three observations for each factor

thank you so much

Nik

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `table` function as follows:

```
subset(df, table(FACTOR)[FACTOR] >= 3)
#    FACTOR VALUE
# 1 ANTONIO     5
# 2 ANTONIO     8
# 3 ANTONIO     7
```

To help you understand, see what these return:

```
table(df$FACTOR)
table(df$FACTOR)[df$FACTOR]
table(df$FACTOR)[df$FACTOR] >= 3
```

---

You could also use the `ave` function to compute the number of observations:

```
subset(df, ave(VALUE, FACTOR, FUN = length) >= 3)
```

This last method may be a little more flexible if you have multiple factors like you asked in your comment and updated question. You can do:

```
subset(df, ave(VALUE, NAME, CLASS, COLOR, FUN = length) >= 3)
```

Comment: ok, so if I have two factor is it still correct in this way?: subset(df,table(factor1,factor2)[factor1]>=3) Thank you so much

Comment: It's not clear, you could edit your question and provide an example of what you mean by two factors (don't forget to give the expected output.)

Comment: ok, i edited my question. Is it more clear? thanks in advance NIk

Comment: Is it possible to use this technique with a dynamic column name? I can't seem to get that to work even if I subscript it (e.g. `table(df[name])[df[name]] >= 3`).

Comment: Never mind. I figured out that you simply have to return a vector in the second situation like `table(df[name])[df[[name]]] >= 3`. I must say though--that's a lot of brackets. :-)